# Why can't an ExtJS component call markInvalid() on itself?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an 3.0.0 ExtJS web application in which I need to have an Ext.form.NumberField have a listener needs be able to mark the NumberField itself invalid.

Trouble is, this doesn't work when I try to call the markInvalid() function from within the listener function.  It works fine when I call it from anywhere else - but not from inside the listener of the number field itself.

Here is the code...

```
var myNumberField = new Ext.form.NumberField({

    id: "myNumberField",

    listeners : {
        'render': function(c) {


            c.getEl().on('keyup', function() {

                this.markInvalid("Marking this invalid!!");
            }, c);

         }
    },
});
```

It's weird - the markInvalid works just fine if I set the component at any other place.  I can even set it fine from another component's listener - I just can't set it in the component itself.  It sort of flashes invalid for an instant, and then goes back.

Please - I'm really at my wit's end with this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because keyup is the default [`validationEvent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-cfg-validationEvent), so what happens is that the field is marked as invalid, and then other validation are processed and the invalid mark is cleared (you can see the mark come and go immediately, don't you?).

One solution could be to disable automatic validation on key press (the field will still [validate on blur](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-cfg-validateOnBlur), you may want to disable that too):

```
var myNumberField = new Ext.form.NumberField({
    id: "myNumberField",

    validationEvent: false, // disable keyup validation

    listeners : {
        'render': function(c) {
            c.getEl().on('keyup', function(e) {
                // the mark will stay!
                this.markInvalid("Marking this invalid!!");
            }, c);
        }
    }
});
```

However, disabling built-in validations (eg. `allowBlank`, `minValue`, etc.) may not be desirable. In this case, you can resume the normal validation process when you don't mark the field invalid yourself. Here's an example on how to do that:

```
var myNumberField = new Ext.form.NumberField({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    id: "myNumberField",

    validationEvent: false, // disable normal keyup validation

    allowBlank: false, // example built-in validator

    listeners : {
        'render': function(c) {
            c.getEl().on('keyup', function(e) {
                // if 'v' is pressed, then validate (the field will be marked
                // as invalid if blank, else invalid will be clear)
                if (e.getKey() === e.V) {
                    this.validate();
                } 
                // if it's another key, we'll mark the field as invalid 
                // and stop
                else {
                    this.markInvalid("Marking this invalid!!");
                }
            }, c);
        }
    }
});
```